# where to find gdal_proximity.py files on ubuntu?

Tags: qgis, gdal, ubuntu

I have installed QGIS, and I use gdal_proximity.py to get a proximity raster, I would like to know where can I find that file on an ubuntu 14.04 distribution.

I ran `find` command in the `.qgis2` directory but got nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's in /usr/bin or /bin depending where your gdal is installed.
Cheers,

Comment: yes found it there, thanks, I thought it would be as an extension to qgis

Comment: `locate gdal_proximity.py` will help if you're stuck

Comment: @dmci I wanted to avoid searching on the whole file system, it takes a lot of time, thanks for your answer